# WPF animation of items between layouts?

Tags: wpf, layout, animation

I have two different ways of displaying items in a WPF application. The first uses a WrapPanel and the second a vertical StackPanel. I can switch between the two ways of displaying my items by switching the host panel between the two types. This does work but you get an instance change in layout.

Instead I want the child items to animate between the two layouts to give a nice smooth effect to the user.  Any ideas how I could go about achieving that? Do I need to a Canvas instead and work out the positioning of children manually? That would be a real pain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the SwitchPanel from IdentityMine's [Blendables Layout](http://www.blendables.com/products/productsLayoutmix.aspx) and also read Dr WPF's article on CodeProject about [Conceptual Children](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ConceptualChildren.aspx)

Comment: The link for Blendables Layout is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted another solution on codeproject that is free and ready to use [WPF Layout to Layout transitions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/466118/WPF-Layout-to-Layout-Transitions)